# Split a word into characters - Unix

Tags: unix, split, character, words

If I have a word called "orange", how do I split it into its individual characters.

My output should be :

```
o
r
a
n
g
e
```

Comment: I was looking for a Unix one-liner....maybe using awk or sed

Answer (score 17):

```
echo orange | fold -w 1
```

output

```
o
r
a
n
g
e
```

Comment: Yep, +1 definitely. Just learned something new ;) Thanks @sehe :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `grep`:

`echo "orange" | grep -o .`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using sed:

```
echo orange | sed 's/./&\n/g'
```

Comment: This will not work on some particular versions of `sed`, such as macos version and supposedly bsd versions.

Comment: @favoretti Well, the other answer is better :)

Answer (score 2):

A pure bash solution (faster than calling external tools, on short strings):

```
$ a="orange"
$ [[ $a =~ ${a//?/(.)} ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
o
r
a
n
g
e
```